# how can I feed GPT2 with prespecified embeddings?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

As the title suggested, I just wonder how can I feed GPT-2 with prespecified embeddings for each word when using the huggingface transformer?

For example, I have embeddings for "q1", "q2" and "q3", say a 3-by-10 matrix (obtained from some other information).

If I use GPT-2 tokenizer, the problems are:

1. token is not 1-to-1 for each word, and there will be 6 tokens. But what I need after fine-tuning is the contexulized embedding for each word, not for each token.
2. I loose a lot of information if I cannot use my embeddings

Comment: Are you planning to use a pretrained gpt? Does your input only consist of custom embeddings or is it a mix of natural language and custom embeddings?